# Making web application fit fully on screen using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to create a responsive `layout` using `React`. I found that the Holy Grail layout fits best to my needs and I am trying to make the one found on this fiddle work (It is not mine): [Holy Grail fiddle](https://codepen.io/takeradi/pen/MyYqKX).

I am also using `video-react` for my video player,  [video-react](https://video-react.js.org/).

The layout I get is not fitting on the screen when it's full size, but fits pretty well when it is in mobile view.

And here is my code:

**App.js**

```
render() {
    const { expanded } = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>

            <nav className="header navbar navbar-light bg-success mb-auto">
                <span className="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" style={{paddingLeft: '10%'}}>Venoossed</span>
            </nav>


            <div className="holygrail-body">
                {/*KokPlayer*/}
                <div className="content">
                    <KokPlayer currentUrl={this.state.source} playerState={this.state.playerState}/>
                </div>

                <div className="side-navigation">
                    <hr />
                    <div style={{width: 'inherit'}}>
                        <Sidenav
                            expanded={expanded}
                            defaultOpenKeys={['3', '4']}
                            activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
                            onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                        >
                            <Sidenav.Body className="bg-light">
                                <Toggle onChange={this.handleToggle} checked={expanded}/>
                                <Nav>
                                    {this.sources.map(source =>
                                        <Nav.Item key={source.id} eventKey={source.id} icon={<Icon icon="dashboard"/>}>
                                            {source.name}
                                        </Nav.Item>
                                    )}

                                    <Dropdown eventKey="3" title="Advanced" icon={<Icon icon="magic" />}>
                                        <Dropdown.Item >Geo</Dropdown.Item>
                                        <Dropdown.Item >Devices</Dropdown.Item>
                                        <Dropdown.Item >Loyalty</Dropdown.Item>
                                        <Dropdown.Item >Visit Depth</Dropdown.Item>
                                    </Dropdown>
                                </Nav>
                            </Sidenav.Body>
                        </Sidenav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <nav className="footer navbar navbar-light bg-success mb-auto">
                <div style={{display: 'block', margin: '0 auto', verticalAlign: 'middle'}}>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.changePlayerState('play')} className="mr-3">
                        play()
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.changePlayerState('pause')} className="mr-3">
                        pause()
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.changePlayerState('fs')} className="mr-3">
                        FullScreen()
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

**holygrail.scss**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
body .header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
}
body .holygrail-body {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
body .holygrail-body .content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}
body .holygrail-body .side-navigation {
  width: auto;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  order: -1;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
body .holygrail-body .flex-aside {
  width: auto;
  background: orange;
}
body .footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: cyan;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  body .holygrail-body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  body .holygrail-body .side-navigation, body .holygrail-body .flex-aside {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I make it fit fully on screen?

**EDIT**

Adding also the `KokPlayer` render part:

```
render() {
    return (

        <div className="video-wrapper">
            <Player ref="player" autoPlay muted>
                <source src={this.props.currentUrl}/>
                <ControlBar disableCompletely/>
            </Player>
        </div>


    );
}
```

The problem is that, It does not care for `header` and `footer` and makes the video-player fit fully on screen, but for some reason it cares that there is a sidenav and fits itself properly. Is there a way to tell the video-player div that it should resize by taking header and footer into account?

Comment: Sorry, but that's a whole load of code I'm not going to plough through.  If it were a **[mcve]** then it would be a different story.  However, generally to make things fill the browser window, set position to absolute and set bottom, left, right & top to 0.

Comment: Fullscreen seems to work as expected. If you're referring to the black bars around one of your videos, then that has to do with the video's aspect ratio being slightly different than your monitor's aspect ratio (hence the black bars). If you're refering to something else, please be more specific as to your issue (and provide pictures).

Comment: @MattCarlotta I am not referring to either of them, what I am referring to is that when you open this page in a browser the page does not fit fully, but it is scrollable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, I see. You're talking about the player's height pushing the application size beyond the current window size. That's what I figured you were talking about.

In that case, the problem arises from the player setting a `padding-top` of around ~56% (see class`.video-react.video-react-16-9, .video-react.video-react-4-3` in the `DOM`). This calculation is off and is causing the player to expand beyond the window's `innerHeight`.

A solution I came up with was to create an `event listener` for the `window.innerHeight` and to calculate a new `padding-top` based upon the current window size. Using `stylized-components` I was then able to apply this new `padding-top` offset to the `.video-react.video-react-16-9, .video-react.video-react-4-3` classes.

**Working example**: https://ox69p34op5.codesandbox.io/ (please note that this example doesn't include any `CSS` breakpoints for mobile devices).

[image: Edit Responsive Video Player]

What the fix looks in the DOM: [image]

Comment: This looks really good and exactly what I need, it's a bit late (time wise) to change it at the moment, but I will give it a try first thing in the morning and let you know. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Tried it out and it worked like a charm. Thank you a lot. But I had to remove `flex-flow: row wrap;` and replace it with `flex-direction: column;` in the `.flex-container`. Because the video would not appear. Also in the phone view, what would you do with the height calculation?

Comment: As soon as you set up breakpoints for other devices, you probably won't need to manually set the `padding-top` height. With mobile/tablet layouts, the layout can be a single column with different rows for each main component (you won't even need to use `display: flex;` -- `display: block;` should suffice). Instead of doing it for you, take a look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp.

Comment: sorry If I am already bothering you but I could not find the answer for this question. Namely I made a new div which is the text that is displayed on the right side of the screen. Now In the mobile view I would like that text to be under the footer. Is there a way to tell the text div (which is pretty much the same as sidenav) that it should go under the footer?

Answer (score 1):

The video react components make the player width take 100%.
To fix it try this when rendering your components:

```
    export default props => {
      return (
        <Player
          playsInline
          poster="/assets/poster.png"
          src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
          fluid={false}
        />
      );
    };
```

Comment: If I set those setting like you said, it only covers about 30% of the screen so I am doing something wrong elsewhere. Also when fluid is set to false it doesnt fit on the screen in mobile view. Any suggestions? I also edited the question and added `KokPlayer`.